# Get Value Of Selected Option ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Without using Ajax is there a way to get the value of a selected item. So for example, if I have the below drop down list:

```
<select name="controllers" id="id_controllers">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">http://przemeklach.com/api/firstOrder/przemeksController</option>
<option value="5">http://przemeklach.com/api/zeroOrder/ronsController</option>
</select>
```

How would I get at the 'value' in my view. I know I can get the 'http://przemeklach.com/api/firstOrder/przemeksController' part via

```
controller = form.cleaned_data['controllers']
```

but I also need the 'value' in this case 1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Scratch the old response (below), cleaned_data contains object references. You can get the ID by refering to model methods.

You can get the id from `form.data['controllers']` but it needs sanity checking (in this case it should be an int). Of course if the `is_valid()` returns True it should be one of the ids available in the queryset you supplied when defining the field.